# Will a drill bit that came with a dremel be good enought to drill out a screw?

Tags: drill, screws

I have a dremel, and I want to know if the drill bits that came with it are good enough to drill out a screw in my shower faucet.

The shower faucet handel is broken and the screw is stuck in the hole. I would like to just drill it out instead of pulling the whole fixture apart.

Answer (score 7):

It should be good enough, even though you are using a rue of thumb.  You might try a screw extractor.

[image: Screw Extractor]

Here's the [instructions](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BwVroAj7GS9tZmY2MWYyMjUtN2VlNS00NmMyLThmMjItMjJjMmI5MmU1NTkx) on using a screw extractor.

Here's a [link](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10451/how-to-remove-screws-with-stripped-heads/10457#10457) from a previous post on suggestions on removing damaged screws.

If you extract it in a good way you won't damage anything and can reuse the old parts.  The screw extractor kit is handy to have around, even if it is only used a couple times a year, if that much.  It easily gets the bad screw out, get a replacement handle and screw a new set screw back in.  If you drill it out, the you risk damaging the threads or you might have to tap the hole and go with a large size that might stick out more than the designed screw.