# Uncommon bolt head

Tags: bolts

Can anybody please tell me what type of bolt is this? I can not find any tool to remove it.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't find the matching tool, you treat screws like this the same as [screws with stripped heads](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10451/how-to-remove-screws-with-stripped-heads).

Comment: Could this be some sort of rivet?

Comment: It is clearly a screw. There are screw threads behind the plate.

Comment: You mean the wider silver-headed object on the flange, or the smaller, darker object just below it? If the former, then I'm guessing it's some kind of security screw meant not to be unscrewed by the unauthorized.

Answer (score 1):

Those are used in vehicles to reduce theft of the attached item.

In the case of the photograph, it is holding in a sound system, perhaps the most commonly stolen item in a vehicle.

I have only seen them in non-automotive applications where someone is using them outdoors to prevent theft.

Comment: Any idea how to remove these? Do I need to cut it or any tool available?

Comment: A dealership for the car brand will be able to order/sell the necessary key, similar to the ones used on wheel nut locks

Comment: Brute force. My first effort would be to set a punch in the groove and try to tap it sideways. Failing that, cut a groove across the head (grinder, hacksaw, oscillating tool) and turn it with a screwdriver).

Answer (score 1):

When I enlarged the picture as big as it would go,(click on the picture, there will be a plus sign with a magnifying glass, then click on it again to get it larger still) I could not see any definition of a bolt head setting on a metal plate to hold something. It looks like a stamp that shaped the metal plate also stamped the presumed bolt head too. If that was truly a  bolt, the lines where the bolt would meet the plate would be clearly defined and I would figure the metal color would at least be slightly different from the bolt to the plate.

I would have no idea why it would be made that way, but it appears to be part of the plate/bracket.

Comment: It is clearly a screw. There are screw threads behind the plate.

Comment: Might it be a plate that covers the head of the bolt? Unless a close up picture of the bolt head is possible it looks like it is all shaped out of the piece. A picture from the side a bit would be helpful. If there is separation there a pair of channel locks would possibly work, or use a dremel tool to cut a slot for a screwdriver